# Questions about mathematical applications in the real world

Tags: discussion

It might be interesting to have questions and answers about topics of real mathematics at the company and its uses: oceanography, a realistic example of control in a partial differential equation, uses of mathematics in netwoks and flows, uses in astronomy, in research operations, realistic uses in financial mathematics... Well the questions, simplified a little.

A problem is that the questions should come from an expert, then possibly they are not genuine, or are more an exposure of subjects that a concise question.

In any case I think it could be an idea for the future.

> **Question.** If you want made feedback about this idea, you are welcome.

Comment: Might be related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2556/real-world-applications-of-mathematics-by-arxiv-subject-area

Comment: Thanks Surb I've modify previous comments, after the question is put on hold

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Information about applications of mathematics to the "real world" might make excellent [blog posts](http://math.blogoverflow.com/). However shoehorning them into "questions" is probably not the best use of the Stack Exchange platform.

Comment: I am agree with you at 100 %, but the truth is that applications, or the expectation and explaining from an expert always provide good knowledge . Now I tell to you that I believe that many questions will be inaccessible without this path. Neither I don't know *blog*, I will try visit it. Thanks @ArthurFischer